# Node.js, path.resolve() "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I've followed the [gatsby.js docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/) to try and generate new pages from markdown entries. Just like the example, I have a line using `path.resolve()`.

```
 ERROR

Error in "/Users/lougro/repos/gatsby-starter-default/gatsby-node.js": Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined



  TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

  - gatsby-node.js:4 Object.<anonymous>
    /Users/lougro/repos/gatsby-starter-default/gatsby-node.js:4:28

  - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30

  - loader.js:991 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10

  - loader.js:811 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32

  - loader.js:723 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14

  - loader.js:848 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19

  - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20

  - resolve-module-exports.js:126 module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/resolve-module-exports.js:126:26

  - validate.js:120
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/validate.js:120:31

  - Array.forEach

  - validate.js:113 collatePluginAPIs
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/validate.js:113:20

  - index.js:62 module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:62:13

  - index.js:181 module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:181:34

  - develop.js:422 async module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/develop.js:422:7
```

When I comment out the line that uses `path.resolve()`, the error goes away (replaced both others where the path is needed, of course).

```js
const EventTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/eventTemplate.js`)
```

I've read the node.js docs on path.resolve() and I can't see how I'm using it incorrectly. What I've got is more or less identical to the example in the gatsby docs.

That said, when I `console.log(path)` it is undefined. Given that I've more or less copy and pasted the example, I don't understand how that could be the case.

I've also, in response to [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1941), tried upgrading and downgrading node.js. I've tried all the following node versions, using the PKG installer for MacOS. Then I `rm -rf node_modules; npm install`. I get the error regardless of node version. I've tried:

- 13.8.0
- 12.15.0
- 12.14.1
- 10.19.0
- 10.15.3
- 10.6.0

What is the solution? What is the problem?

Comment: You are definitely importing the `path` module?

Comment: Please show us your code.  We need to basically see the whole module where this code resides because you are either mistakenly redeclaring a variable in some local scope named `path` which overrides the `path` module or you are not properly importing the `path` module.  We can only help you when we can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not use `path.resolve()`.

I was referring to both a video course on Udemy and the example. The course uses `path.resolve()`. The gatsby example uses `require.resolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I needed to use the `path` module, and here's what worked for me.

I was including a step in my NestJS app that would write the OpenAPI spec to a file. It looks like this:

```
try {
  const filepath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'open-api.json');
  fs.writeFileSync(filepath, JSON.stringify(document), 'utf8');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to generate open-api.json: ', error);
}
```

I had originally imported `path` and `fs` the same way I always have, and the same way I had done it in another project where this exact approach was working just fine:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
```

But on running the app I received the same error as OP. When removing the call to `path` entirely, I received the same error for `fs`.

Changing node versions didn't make a difference, but it resolved when I changed my imports to look like this:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Not sure what it is about my specific setup for this project that made this the answer, but hopefully it can help someone else!